# How to set TextFormField dynamically?

Tags: flutter

I am using flutter and I want to set text (String value) in TextFormField dynamically, means set value over press of a button.

Comment: Please add the code to your question that demonstrates what you try to accomplish, what you tried and where you failed. StackOverflow is not a fee code-monkey service.

Comment: there's a session in the cookbooks dedicated to forms: https://flutter.io/cookbook/

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer  i got your point. Actually  my question is that i want to pick contact number from contact list and set in TextFormField.

Answer (score 5):

use TextEditingController. Then assign it to the TextFormField then make use of the controller to assign the new data from wherever you want. If you want initial data assign it some value in the initState() function also use it on a stateful widget.
_textEditingController.text = "1";

Comment: Please do not forget to dispose the texteditingcontroller:

    @override
    void dispose() {
        _myTextEditingController.dispose();
        super.dispose();
    }

Answer (score 3):

You can make use of a ***[`StatefulWidget`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/StatefulWidget-class.html)*** to adjust the [`initialValue` property](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/FormField/initialValue.html) of your `TextFormField`.

```
class TextFieldChanger extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TextFieldChangerState createState() => _TextFieldChangerState();
}

class _TextFieldChangerState extends State<TextFieldChanger> {
  String presetText;

  void _onPressed() {
    setState(() {
      presetText = 'updated text';
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Column(children: [
    TextFormField(initialValue: presetText),
    RawMaterialButton(onPressed: _onPressed),
  ]);
}
```

In *`setState`*, I am assigning a new value to *`presetText`* and **`build`** will be called (with the *updated* `initialValue`) because of `setState`.